# Matplotlib invalid syntax (__init__.py, line 3) when importing matplotlib as mpl

Tags: python, matplotlib

I installed matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib`, and I'm trying to import it but when I run my script I'm getting a syntax error in the `__init__.py` (line 3). Here's my code and the error I'm getting. I'm running python 3.10.4 and matplotlib 3.5.3.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```
 Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
 invalid syntax (__init__.py, line 3)
 File "C:\path\to\my\script.py", line 1, in <module>
 import matplotlib as mpl
```

Edit: Resolved by reinstalling venv

Comment: What are the lines above those?

Comment: line 3 is `import numpy as np`...  so why `matplotlib` ?

Comment: @MattDMo There are no lines above these.

Comment: @D.L I think it's saying line 1 is giving me the error, but the underlying error is line 3 in init.py of the matplotlib library. Could be misreading it though. I get the same syntax error saying the error is on line 2 when I comment out the first import line.

Comment: if you import each module on its own, you would identify the module that fails...

Comment: @D.L The failing module is matplotlib. No matter how many times I uninstall and reinstall I get this same error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ...and the other modules work ?   which version of python did you install matplotlib to and which version of python are you running ?

Comment: @D.L I've installed matplotlib to the venv, and just for giggles I installed it on the machine's environment. Neither have worked. Versions listed above. I'm running python 3.10.4 and matplotlib 3.5.3.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of the error and traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @MattDMo Not trying to be difficult, but haven't I already done that with "Exception has occurred..."? That's the full error I'm getting. I'm new to this so I apologize if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Bommel so there's absolutely no other text than that? How do you know that `__init__.py` is referring to the one from `matplotlib`? Your script isn't named `matplotlib.py` or in a folder named `matplotlib` by chance, is it?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm just about stumped. One more thing to try: Save your file. Open a clean Command Prompt (hit Win-R, type in `cmd` and hit Enter), navigate to your venv's directory, run `bin\activate.bat` so you're using its `python.exe` and `site-packages`, then run your script - `python C:\Users\you\OneDrive\path\to\script.py` and see if you get any errors. If you do, delete your whole venv and make a new one from scratch, making sure to choose its Python executable in VSCode. If you don't get any errors, the issue is with VSCode itself.

Comment: @MattDMo YES! So I ran exactly what you outlined and it pointed me to an issue in `pyparsing\__init__.py, line 3` within my venv, instead of matplotlib. I deleted that venv and created a fresh one with the packages installed that I needed for my scripts and it ran fine. Thanks so much for your patience and help!

Comment: `pyparsing`, eh? I know the guy that maintains it. Anyways, I'm glad you got to the root of your problem. Cheers!